# Insert Page Break after n number of rows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using html2pdf to export html to pdf in AngularJS the issue I have is that I need to insert a page break after n number of rows.. BDW I am using dir-paginate...

Here is my code:

```
<tr data-index="{{$index}}"
    dir-paginate="(ikey,iitem) in products | itemsPerPage:10">`
```

I tried different solutions but nothing works
I have to insert a div with `class="html2pdf__page-break` and repeat the header for example every 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take the rest of the division and check if it is a multiplier of 10, like so:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
       <div ng-if="$index % 10 == 0">
          <!-- do something every 10 items -->
       </div>
       <div ng-if="$index % 10 != 0">
          <!-- else do another something -->
       </div>
       <div>
          <!-- do something everytime -->
       </div>
   </div>
```

You could do it using a function of something like that to keep it cleaner, but the ideia is the same.
Adapt it to your code, or add a codepen/jsfidle so we could help you better.
Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes but the issue is that I am using dir-paginate and not ng-repeat and the other is that I am printing a table and then have to split the table in n rows and repeat the header...

Comment: A simple way (and probably cleaner) why don't you create you custom object with the data that you want? Lets say `$scope.table`, then create a list of header and rows (`$scope.table.headers` and `$scope.table.rows`) and then you simply push 10 items for each row... then you can simply loop trough all rows and inside each row loop trough all 10 items... that way you could just control everything within a script

Comment: I am not clear.. can you show me an example of code.. thank you.

Comment: I just can't help you a lot only with that code... but what I'm trying to explain is that you can create your custom object to use... in my example I just used `ng-repeat`, because it is simple to create a fiddle... You need to create the logic somewhere into your script... [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1z7ohubk/2/)